# How could i calculate the voltage induced in a detector circuit by picking up RF signals from a Mobile phone?

Tags: rf, bjt, power-electronics

[image: l]

Is there any formula/equation i could use to estimate the voltage induced at the input from the RF signals?

Comment: What antenna? What frequency?

Answer (score 1):

This circuit depends on the MOSFETS, in the first differential pair of the CA3130, acting as rectifiers albeit not very good rectifiers, because the fundamental MOSFET bandwidth depends upon channel-spacing from source-to-drain but the rectification depends upon the **junctions** of the MOSFET, such as the source-bulk isolation-junctions and not on the channel-spacing.

And the part number ---CA3130--- is a part number from the 1970s (thus 40+ years ago). To presume the same process is used today is not a good presumption.

Summary ---- you are asking about the UHF (30-300MHz) and SHF (300 to 3,000MHz) rectification efficiency of isolation-diodes of unknown doping profile and of unknown biasing condition (both voltage and idling currents).

Answer: no.